# Adding slide titles in Powerpoint from an Excel file

Tags: vba, vb.net, powerpoint

I am trying to add slide title in a ppt from an excel file. But I am not able to put it in a loop. Each cell from A1 to A7 has slide titles in the file and accordingly I want to put titles in the slides as per slide number. 
Below is the code that I have written.

```
For i = 1 To 7
With Application.Presentations(1)

    For Each ppSlide In .Slides()
       If ppSlide.Shapes.HasTitle Then ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1)
    Next ppSlide

End With

Next i
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the delayed response. I am completely packed in the project hence didn't get a chance to update it here. It works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you run VBA-code within PowerPoint.

You can only set the slide title, if you found the correspondig shape which contains the title. This shape can be recognised by its `Shape.Type = msoPlaceholder` and `PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle` (or `PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderCenterTitle`).

If you want loop from 1 to 7, then you can address the slides by their index from 1 to 7 also (and not by an additional `For Each` loop over all slides).

```
Private Sub SetTitlesFromExcellist()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.worksheet
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xlWorkSheet = xlApp.ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To 7
        Set ppSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
        If ppSlide.Shapes.HasTitle Then
            For Each ppShape In ppSlide.Shapes
                If ppShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                    Select Case ppShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                    Case ppPlaceholderCenterTitle, ppPlaceholderTitle
                        ppShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1)
                        Exit For
                    End Select
                End If
            Next ppShape
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```